# Flutter GetXController : "Unhandled Exception: '!isClosed': You cannot add event to closed Stream"

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

For a couple of hours, I have been struggling with this issue. There are some solutions for BLoC and StreamController but there is no proper solution for GetX.

As their suggestion from BloC answer, I got an idea that it might be related to **GetXController dispose**. Then I apply **dispose()** method for the controller on my page where I initialized the user_controller. But still having the error like below

```
Unhandled Exception: 'package:get/get_rx/src/rx_stream/get_stream.dart': Failed assertion: line 90 pos 12: '!isClosed': You cannot add event to closed Stream
E/flutter (21576): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:46:39)
E/flutter (21576): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:36:5)
E/flutter (21576): #2      GetStream.add (package:get/get_rx/src/rx_stream/get_stream.dart:90:12)
E/flutter (21576): #3      NotifyManager.addListener.<anonymous closure> (package:get/get_rx/src/rx_types/rx_core/rx_impl.dart:139:15)
E/flutter (21576): #4      GetStream._notifyData (package:get/get_rx/src/rx_stream/get_stream.dart:47:21)
E/flutter (21576): #5      GetStream.add (package:get/get_rx/src/rx_stream/get_stream.dart:92:5)
E/flutter (21576): #6      RxObjectMixin.value= (package:get/get_rx/src/rx_types/rx_core/rx_impl.dart:101:13)
E/flutter (21576): #7      UserController.getUserData (package:hellobabybox/controllers/user_controller.dart:20:12)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this just after the declaration of the controller on the stateless widget:

```
controller.onInit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add an event after the controller has been disposed of.  The Controller disposals can happen on widget disposal.  You need to trace when that method is getting called.

Comment: Thanks for ur response, I got your point. At first I didn't call dispose() method neither in my widget class nor in GetXController extended class. btw let me try to trace

Comment: Any idea how to trace it? I too get this message, nothing else!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error just a few minutes ago. And started to search about the error. I found [this on GitHub](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/819#issuecomment-824665192). It was the answer for me.

> Not sure if it helps, but I have the same issue and the issue is solved if I **restart** application without using hot reload.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific fix for this particular issue I guess. I was facing the same issue for a long. Then I find out, there was a `null` pointer exception thrown by some other function inside the class. and after that entire `RxList` that I used, stuck. So, the solution is, if you are facing this kind of issue, try to find out the error thrown by another line of codes.

Answer (score -2):

I have never used that library myself, but I think this will give you some idea.

```dart
StreamController controller = ...;
if (!controller.isClosed) {
  controller.add(event); // Only add the event if the stream isn't closed. 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But I saw this answer where it posted, and then apply dispose(). bcz there is no sink method under controller class in GetX library

Comment: @MimuSahaTishan You can ignore `sink` if there is any `add` method in it. Is there?

Comment: yah tried also but no add method available