# Failed assertion: line 95 pos 12: '!isClosed': You cannot add event to closed Stream?? when calling an APi Using getX ,

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

When I'm calling my API I want to show a Circular Progress Indicator till API request fetch data.
but Flutter GetX Give error

```
   try{
      isLoading(true);
      profileModel = await ProfileRequest.getProfile();
      isEmailVarified =  profileModel.provider.isEmailVerified;
      isPhoneVarified = profileModel.provider.isPhoneNumberVerified;
      }catch(Exception ){
      print("Exception :$Exception");
    }finally{
      isLoading(false);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please include the code of your view/widget where you are using this?

Comment: yes sure:
'Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
        child: Obx((){
          if(profileController.isLoading.value){
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            );
          }else{
           return ListView(
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 40,
                              ),
                ),'

Comment: @AbdulRahmanPanhyar edit your question and add some code like your api call function and your view

Comment: I think the issue is related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69527076/10659482